# SQL Server 2008 ghost backup

Tags: sql-server-2008

Recently installed sqlserver 2008.  there was a uninstall and a reinstall that happened.  for some reason i now have a "ghost" backup that is happening on 2 of my databases. I have created and deleted maintenance plans while trying to "tweek" the backups, so I think somehow that has gotten corrupted.  There currently is not a maintenance plan backing up these databases to the path that the backups are occurring.  I have a job that is running to delete these extra copies but I would like to find out how to kill this job.  Any ideas would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

If the backups are happening on a regular basis there could be a SQL Agent job that is left over from something.  Look through the jobs on the server and see if any of them are running a backup.

A couple of Common things to look for are:

- Jobs with '.Subplan_1' at the end (or a different number than 1)
- Jobs that run an SSIS package and the package path starts with 'Maintenance Plans'